# Running iOS App in background for more than 10 minutes

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, background-process

I am trying to allow my app to run in the background for more that 10 minutes, according to this and my good below. (I want to use long background running to keep track of a location, my code here simply just use a counter for testing purposes)
Anyone can help point out what the problem is?

> *Implementing Long-Running Background Tasks*
>
> For tasks that require more execution time to implement, you must
>   request specific permissions to run them in the background without
>   their being suspended. In iOS, only specific app types are allowed to
>   run in the background:
>
> Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background,
>   such as a music player app
>
> Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as
>   a navigation app
>
> Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
>
> Newsstand apps that need to download and process new content Apps that
>   receive regular updates from external accessories
>
> Apps that implement these services must declare the services they
>   support and use system frameworks to implement the relevant aspects of
>   those services. Declaring the services lets the system know which
>   services you use, but in some cases it is the system frameworks that
>   actually prevent your application from being suspended.

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
             [super viewDidLoad];

        counterTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
                       beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

                       }];
                count=0;

        theTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(countUp)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];
         }
    - (void)countUp {

        {
            count++;
            NSString *currentCount;
            currentCount=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%ld",count];
            theCount.text=currentCount;
            [currentCount release];
        }
        }
```

**Another Question:** Can I have an iOS App run in the background forever?

----Edited code to add location, still doesnt run for more than 10 mins, any help to what i'm doing wrong?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

 count=0;

locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

 [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

counterTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
               beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
                   // If you're worried about exceeding 10 minutes, handle it here

                   [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
               }];
theTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
                                          target:self
                                        selector:@selector(countUp)
                                        userInfo:nil
                                         repeats:YES];

 }



     (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
 NSLog(@"OldLocation %f %f", oldLocation.coordinate.latitude, oldLocation.coordinate.longitude); NSLog(@"NewLocation %f %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);

    count++; NSString *currentCount;
 currentCount=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%ld",count];
 theCount.text=currentCount; [currentCount release];
 }

    (void)countUp { [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
 { count++; NSString *currentCount; 
currentCount=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%ld",count]; 
theCount.text=currentCount;
 [currentCount release]; } }
```

Comment: You have specified wich apps can run in the background if you app does not falls in one of those categories then you are out if luck. Not there is not way to make you app run in background forever. Apple will not allow this because it will kill battery life. Nor do I as an user ever want an app like this. Why would your app need to be running all the time???

Comment: it does fall under the specified categories specifically (Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app) 

when i test the code background tasks stay for only 10 minutes, should i use the location also for testing instead of just the counter?

Comment: If you app use the location in background, you should start `CLLocationManager` for receiving major location changes. Then your app will be informed when the user changes location.

Comment: Thank you, will test it now, and tell you what happens

Comment: rckoenes, i edited the question with the new code that includes the cllocation, please any help to what i am doing wrong, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So your app uses location services. Then please read the [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html).

You need to make some changes to your Info.plist:

- If your app relies on location services to function properly, add `location-services` to `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`
- if your app requires GPS hardware, add `gps` to `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`
- **if  you need to run your app longer then 10 minutes in the background, add `location` to `UIBackgroundModes`. Then your location manager will deliver locations beyond the 10-minute-limit.**
- you should also set `NSLocationUsageDescription` (can also be localized)

> *Getting Location Events in the Background*
>
> If your app needs location updates delivered whether the app is in the
>   foreground or background, there are multiple options for doing so. The
>   preferred option is to use the significant location change service to
>   wake your app at appropriate times to handle new events. However, if
>   your app needs to use the standard location service, you can declare
>   your app as needing background location services.
>
> An app should request background location services only if the absence
>   of those services would impair its ability to operate. In addition,
>   any app that requests background location services should use those
>   services to provide a tangible benefit to the user. For example, a
>   turn-by-turn navigation app would be a likely candidate for background
>   location services because of its need to track the user’s position and
>   report when it is time to make the next turn.

Comment: Thank you for reply, i made the changes you wrote, but i didnt know how to do the last point (you should also set NSLocationUsageDescription (can also be localized))

Please also check my above code
Thank you a lot for your help

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem is fixed :D

Answer (score 1):

See [phix23](http://stackoverflow.comhttps://stackoverflow.com/a/16031860/2998)'s answer (and the documentation) for the details, but here I want to explain what you can expect to happen.

This is all pretty much covered in the documentation that you quoted from.

Any application can run in the background for up to ten minutes. That's what the `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` method does. No matter which flags and options you set, that's all you'll get using that method.

For apps that need to keep track of location you can use `CLLocationManager`. This does not allow your app to run in the background as long as you like. Instead it notifies you when something interesting happens -- that's what the delegate is for. So you can't guarantee that your `countUp` method gets called every ten minutes, but you *can* have the OS call it when the user moves their handset a certain distance.

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem is fixed :D

Answer (score 1):

By adding the following in the `applicationDidEnterBackground` method, it seems that it can execute forever:

```
[app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{}];
```

Then you invalidate the long task in the `willEnterForeground`.

I succeed in iOS 6 recently, but I'm not sure it would be approved for the store.

Comment: Definitely would NOT be approved for the store. Nice hack though!

Answer (score 0):

By the way, in your plist you can alos set `Required background modes` and then in Item0 `App registers for location updates`